# ext4 Filesystem Corrupt - Bad Drive. Fsck Failing. How to Recover?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem

I run a small Linux-Based openmediavault home media server in my house stacked full of drives, no RAID or backup (don't have the space) and it's all media files.

I noticed a a 3 TB drive full of multimedia downloads started acting up when I streamed video from it so I went to the shell and ran an fsck -fy on it.  Lots of errors:

1. "Group descriptor XXXX checksum is XXXXX, should be XXXXX, FIXED
   Block bitmap for group XXXX is not in group.
   WARNING: SERVERE DATA LOSS POSSIBLE"
   relocate? (Y)"
   (Hundreds of those.)
2. "Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
   CLEARED
3. *** ext3 journal has been deleted - filesystem is now ext2 only *** "
   Tons of "Buffer I/O error on device sdX1, logical block XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   "Error reading block XXXXXX (attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while getting next inode from scan)."

I want this drive out of my system and in the garbage as fast as possible, however, I'd really like a shot at getting any remaining data that is on there (whatever I did not already corrupt further by running these fsck -f -y -c -t commands and saying yes to everything)...

I am mainly a Windows desktop user and a "set and forget" user with Linux so I'm hoping there might be some tricks/commands I can run on this drive to try and at least mount it to get at my content.  I can't seem to even get the drive mounted now -- Even went to far to try and connect it to my Mac desktop running MacFUSE and the Mac only saw the 800 MB that was free (didn't even see the 2.2 TB ext4 partition that held all the data files.  I think my partitions are way messed up.

I did run a dumpe2fs | grep superblock command on the file system and there were a ton of backup superblocks it found, which may be good news and somewhere to start?

Even if I can get SOME data off this thing, I'll be happy.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

If you feel more comfortable using Windows, there's http://www.ext2fsd.com/, or ext file system for Windows.
If you install that and then mount the drive in a Windows computer, you should be able to read the partitions and remaining data.
Otherwise, boot from a livecd and try to copy remaining data to another location (other drive, network, whatever).
Also try to check the disk with diagnostic tools (bios tools? hirens? ubcd?) to see if the drive is actually failing, or just the file system on it. There's a tiny little chance you can save the drive

But seriously, just like you know that every living thing will die one day, you know that hard drives give up too. Some sooner, others later. You just can't tell. Either make sure you have a backup, redundant RAID or just live with the loss.
If it's all downloaded media, chances are you can download it again and it's not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and add another hdd to your rig and setup your OS again. Once you have a stable system, if the drive isnt completely toast you should be able to mount it and attempt to recover your data from it.
You will need to keep both hdd in the case and connected btw.
Once the old hdd is mounted to the new OS and both are EXT4 you should be able to navigate the old hdd file system with the native file browser.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.  This is actually just a data drive that went bad.  My system boots from an external SSD drive and contains 11 full size hard drives full of multimedia files.  This was just one of those 11 drives.  I can boot the OS and into openmediavault just fine.  But once I get in there, can't seem to get the drive to mount.  Was thinking of yanking the drive and putting it into an enclosure and connecting it to a PC running a Live Linux CD and trying to work with it from in there maybe?  What I could use help with are some safe fsck-type commands to run against the data.

Comment: At work when this sort of thing happens we use an external drive bay that we connect via usb, so yeah, maybe, but it should work without doing that with the setup you're describing. But, yeah, file system repair utilities sound like you're best friend. Or try looking for a disk mirroring utility that can try and mirrior over the failed hdd's data to a fresh one.